# Workspace grey blank

Tags: modeling, objects, interface, 3d-view

When I work with 2 split screen, one screen has a blank gray. I don't remember if there is a letter button that was pushed accidentally.

[image: enter image descripasasas here]

This fullscreen picture
[image]

Who knows my friends all have a solution, Thank you very much :)

Comment: Probably *Only Render* is checked in the Properties shelf > Display rollout. Do you want to disable that grey area? Or do you want to achieve it?

Comment: thanks for answering my question, only render is not checked

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve problems like this, my guessing abilities aren't always working. Another possibility is that you zoomed out too much, then select pants in the right viewport (or in the Outliner) and press Numpad period while hovering mouse over left viewport to center camera on it. Or just join the views on the right one and split again. If any of the solutions below answered your question mark them as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the top. It says "Back to Previous" -> That's how you get back.

What happened is that you accidentally hit Shift + Space Bar. This makes the current View go full screen. (The one your mouse is over)
Alternatively you can just hit Shift + Space Bar again.

EDIT:

On the other hand, if you have trouble finding the geometry in your 3D view, you can either use Shift + C as pointed out by @HenrikD or, press "." or "," on your Num Pad to center the view on a selected object.

Comment: Their question is about why that view is empty, not why it's fullscreen.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the way you read the question, @Brenticus. I think both ways are possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to join the views again and split them up again, because in general when you split a view both new views are exactly the same. Also you are probably just looking somewhere outside you "scene" try pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: thanks for answering my question, when i try shift + c in left split screen as blank gray is nothing happen, but when i try shift + c in right split screen, the right part to gray like the left.